# express.js req.uri variable without parameters

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Folks
  I am trying to grab a variable `req.url`, however it includes the parameters that users pass in.

Is there a different object i can grab, ie `req.uri` that does not have the extra variables?

Thanks!

Comment: drop everythin after `?` ?

Comment: i guess that would be one way :)

Comment: `req.url.split('?').shift()`

Comment: or `url.parse(req.url).pathname`

Comment: which is most efficient?